# Error providing image from another site

Tags: php

Basically what I want to do is have a section on my site, where you provide the username of a user, example: NOTCH

Where it then goes to the minecraft host and finds the user's skin. "Skin Stealer" if you like.

However I'm getting an error and have no idea how to get around it..

```
<?php
if ($_GET['user'])
{
$user = $_GET['user'];

if(trim($user) == '')
{
    die('No username entered!');
}

$user = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $user);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$picture = '<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$user.png">';
$getpicture = file_get_contents("$picture");
echo $picture
}
?>
```

The HTML is just a basic form which reads the php page called 'mcskin.php'

Comment: And the error is?  You probably don't want to stick HTML into `file_get_contents` just the URL but you should probably use cURL instead.

Comment: Oops sorry forgot to add that in :P! You can check the here: http://laimwmckenzie.com/mc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using file_get_contens you just need the url:

```
$picture = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$user.png";
```

Also change

```
$getpicture = file_get_contents("$picture");
```

to

```
$getpicture = file_get_contents($picture);
```

Comment: I'm currently getting this error: http://laimwmckenzie.com/mc/mcskin.php?user=Liaaaaaaaammm (I've changed everything you've said)

Comment: You missed a ; on the previous line.

Comment: I've added it in, I now have this http://puu.sh/2kUP6 but I'm getting this error http://laimwmckenzie.com/mc/mcskin.php?user=Liaaaaaaaammm

Comment: You have not changed the $picture = line as I told you!

Comment: Still giving WHAT error? And the image http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/Liaaaaaaaammm.png does not exist!

Comment: I should really describe things more. This error: http://laimwmckenzie.com/mc/mcskin.php?user=Notch

Comment: Sheesh, do you have ANY idea what you are doing? Try looking at what you are getting from s3. I am seeing http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/Notch.png
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: I'm not getting that ._. I'm getting 'invalid file' Ill clear my cache and refresh the page.

Comment: You certainly are getting that, because that is the contents of the "image" that your link is sending to my browser. I examined it in Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the right quotes:

```
$picture = "<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$user.png'>";
```

And in this line quotes are not needed:

```
$getpicture = file_get_contents($picture);
```

Also you are aplying `file_get_contents()` to the `img` tag which make no sense. Pass it the URL:

```
$pictureUrl = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$user.png";
$getpicture = file_get_contents($pictureUrl);
```

Comment: That won't fix his problem. He shouldn't be passing the html into file_get_contents.

Comment: @mkaatman Yeah I just realized that, thanks for noticing. I think my update covers all the errors.